# How do I make this div to stay in a position after it has moved?

Tags: css

After the div moves left 300px, It should stop. If I take the `infinite` out It goes back to 0 and stays there. I Want it to stay left 300px and then not move back. `animation-iteration-count: 1;` doesn't help.

html:

```
<div id="div1">linear</div>
```

css:

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite; 
}


@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  from {left: 0px;}
  to {left: 300px;}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the [`animation-fill-mode` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) to `forwards`:

```
-webkit-animation: mymove 5s forwards;
animation: mymove 5s forwards;
```

This property determines how the element is styled before/after the animation is executed. Setting the value to `forwards` will force the element to retain the values that were set by the last keyframe (in this case, `left: 300px`).

Basic example:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: mymove 5s forwards;
  animation: mymove 5s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  from {
    left: 0px;
  }
  to {
    left: 300px;
  }
}
@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    left: 0px;
  }
  to {
    left: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: And a link to the specifications for [`animation-fill-mode`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-animations/#propdef-animation-fill-mode).

Answer (score 1):

As the `animation-fill-mode` is still experimental, you can do like this.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;
  left: 300px;
  animation: mymove 5s; 
}


@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  from {left: 0px;}
  to {left: 300px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">linear</div>
```

Comment: @JoshCrozier Thanks, and I know, I just also know that some won't use experimental stuff in production environment, so I thought it could be a good option.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know it was experimental. This evolved and I mixed both of your answer and it worked at one point for something else I was doing.